# jump between frames

Tags: beamer

As we all know one can jump between frames [using e.g. hyperlinks.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43555/conditionally-hidden-slides-in-beamer)

I don't want jump to the end, but include the frames fixed. They should not be additional. E.g. I have the topic cars and make an excursion about motors coming back to cars.

When I added the intermediate "motor" part, I had the problems, that my table of content showed the "car" section twice and the tree view too.

It was possible to fix the ToC with `\section*{car}` but not the 'tree view'.

Here an example (what I want to modify are the words in the top row):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%using my default theme
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{shadow}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{cars}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{there are so many different cars}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Transmissions
        \item Motors
        \item Drive shafts
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{motors}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{and motors are also interesting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item big motor
        \item small motor
        \item tiny motor
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section*{cars}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{coming back to cars}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Cars need fuel
        \item Cars are expensive
        \item Cars bring us from a to be
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide1]
[image: slide2]
[image: slide3]
[image: slide4]

Is there another command that determines the next frame and forces beamer to "reorder" the document, or jump to the end?

Maybe it is possible to reset the table of content counter?

Thank you for your help,
Greets

Comment: Could you show an example demonstrating the problems with the ToC?

Comment: And should "motor" appear in the toc? And if yes where ant at which level (e.g. as section, subsection or something else)?

Comment: @samcarter : yes motor should appear in the toc. I would prefer as normal section.
It s a normal part of the presentation and such it should be in the toc. But when I go through the presentation 'car' should not be twice in the top row.

Comment: What was the problem with the deleted solution exactly? It is set up to only show some slides of the frame initially, so there's no need to skip through anything to get to to motors section.

Comment: well unfortunately it got deleted. I can't remember excatly but I commented the deleted version and wrote down my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, you can succeed with some counter manipulation. I added a new section 'traffic jam', so that you can see that everything is working as expected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is your modified code, leading to the results shown above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%using my default theme
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{cars}
% Save the section counter in the cars section
\newcounter{carscounter}\setcounter{carscounter}{\thesection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{there are so many different cars}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Transmissions
        \item Motors
        \item Drive shafts
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{motors}
% Save the section counter in the motors section
\newcounter{motorscounter}\setcounter{motorscounter}{\thesection}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{and motors are also interesting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item big motor
        \item small motor
        \item tiny motor
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
% Set section counter to the proviously stored value
\setcounter{section}{\value{carscounter}}
    \frametitle{coming back to cars}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Cars need fuel
        \item Cars are expensive
        \item Cars bring us from a to be
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{further things}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Some more car things
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

% Before adding the next section, we have to set the counter accordingly, so that everything is in correct order again (otherwise the top view panel will go crazy)
\setcounter{section}{\value{motorscounter}}
\section{traffic jams}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{one major problem of cars are traffic jams}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item long traffic jams
        \item short traffic jams
        \item and, of course, boring ones
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Excactly doing what it should do! Good solution. Thank you.