# Remove slide from ToC and navigation in beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to have a slide at the end of my presentation be not included in the ToC or the navigation bar at the top.

The solution used to be to put it in a `\section*{}`. But at some point in the last year or so, this stopped working! (I recompiled some slides I wrote a year ago, which originally worked as expected, but the result changed this time.) The ToC looks fine but the offending slide still appears in the navigation header.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{frame}
hi
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
hi hi
\end{frame}

\section*{}

\begin{frame}
bye
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(Note that on the 4th slide, the "Section 1" and the first two circles are grayed out.)

**Edit:** Creating an `\appendix` for the final slide has an effect, but not exactly the desired one. The circle for the final slide no longer appears as part of Section 1, but instead it appears by itself in the top right corner, only on the final slide.

**Edit:** [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/24974) fixed the problem, though it's still not clear to me why the original method no longer works.

Comment: Try using an appendix [(duplicate?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21252/24974)

Comment: @erik This removes the offending circle from Section 1, but instead it appears at the top right by itself on the final slide.

Comment: See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45038/24974), and add `\miniframesoff` before the final slide.

Comment: You can replace frame with a minipage so there is no frame counter to link to.

Comment: related beamer issue: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/471