# How to correct \insertpresentationendpage in presence of \uncover

Tags: beamer, numbering, appendices, overlays

The command `\insertpresentationendpage` is supposed to insert the page number of the last page of the presentation, excluding the appendix.  However its value is incorrectly increased if `\uncover` is used during the presentation.  Does anyone know a good fix or workaround for this problem?

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\insertpresentationendpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Slide one
  %Comment out next line to get desired behaviour
  \uncover<2>{still} 
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
  Slide two (appendix)
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  Slide three (appendix)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found a similar query with a bit more information [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.latex.beamer.general/1).

Comment: Of course, in the interim, one work-around is to specify this manually. That is, find the last frame (say `20`) and use `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/20}`.

Comment: Thanks Werner, that is my current solution.  My worry is it can easily go wrong if I forget to update this command after a hasty edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually the intended behaviour. Compare the description of `\inserttotalframenumber` and `\insertpresentationendpage` in the [`beamer` manual (p. 66)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=66):

> `\inserttotalframenumber` Inserts the total number of the frames (not slides) into a template. The number is only correct on the second run of TeX on your document.

vs.

> `\insertpresentationendpage` Inserts the page number of the last page of the presentation (excluding
>   the appendix).

So `\inserttotalframenumber` counts the number of *frames*, which means it isn't increased in frames with overlays, while `\insertpresentationendpage` counts the absolute number of *pages* in the presentation, with each overlay as a single page.

What you're looking for instead is an `\insertpresentationendframe` command, which is unfortunately not available in `beamer`. However, you can define it yourself:

```
\def\insertpresentationendframe{\inserttotalframenumber}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}{\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\def\noexpand\insertpresentationendframe{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}
\makeatother
```

Insert this code into the preamble of your document, i. e. somewhere between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`. It defines a macro `\insertpresentationendframe` which defaults to the total number of frames, but is "locked" to the number of the last frame of the main presentation if an appendix is encountered.

Using it is straightforward:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\def\insertpresentationendframe{\inserttotalframenumber}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\appendix}{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}{\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\def\noexpand\insertpresentationendframe{\the\c@framenumber}}}}}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertframenumber/\insertpresentationendframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Slide one
  \uncover<2>{still} 
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
  Slide two (appendix)
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  Slide three (appendix)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Observe that the frame counter now correctly shows `1/1` instead of `1/2`.