# Don't count backup slides

Tags: beamer

I prepare some backup slides at the end of my presentation. I don't want them to be counted in terms of pages, which is displayed at the footer of each slide.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Does this post answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732902/ignoring-page-numbers-in-backup-slides ?

Comment: Surely I misunderstood the question, but if you have just backup slides to not show... why not just put before an extra `\end{document}`? For see again the backups the only thing needed is put  `%` before.

Comment: @Fran as I understand the question, SoftTimur do want those frames to appear, he just doesn't want them to be taken into account when calculating the total number of frames/slides.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2541/35864.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here are two solutions inspired from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732902/ignoring-page-numbers-in-backup-slides) given in my above comment.

1. You can define a new counter at the end of your presentation, before your backup slides, and use this counter at the end of your backup slides to fool beamer on the total number of slides. Here is a MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usetheme{Madrid}

   \newcommand{\backupbegin}{
      \newcounter{finalframe}
      \setcounter{finalframe}{\value{framenumber}}
   }
   \newcommand{\backupend}{
      \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{finalframe}}
   }

   \begin{document}
   % Your normal slides go here 
   \frame{\lipsum[1]}
   \frame{\lipsum[2]}

   \appendix
   \backupbegin
   % And your backup slides here
   \frame{\lipsum[3]}
   \backupend

   \end{document}
   ```

   In this case, the backup slide is numbered as 3/2 in this example.
2. Alternatively, you can use the [`appendixnumberbeamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendixnumberbeamer) package. MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}

   \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usetheme{Madrid}
   \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

   \begin{document}
   % Your normal slides go here 
   \frame{\lipsum[1]}
   \frame{\lipsum[2]}

   \appendix
   % And your backup slides here
   \frame{\lipsum[3]}

   \end{document}
   ```

   In this case, the backup slide is numbered as 1/1.

Comment: For the second proposal, the displayed total number of slides is equal to the number of (normal+backup), instead of (normal) only. e.g. the entire presentation has 10 slides, 7 normal and 3 backup. At the 7th slide (which is normal), the displayed number is 7/10 instead of 7/7.

Comment: Compile twice, this will give you 7/7

Answer (score 8):

As of this post, beamer includes `\insertmainframenumber`. Unlike `\inserttotalframenumber`, `\insertmainframenumber` only counts slides before the appendix--no package dependencies, custom commands, or other tricks needed!

I know this is old, but this problem wasted hours of my life and I want to make sure anyone searching for this finds this solution quickly! I guess it pays to read the manual, but I was discouraged because it is so long and dense and I am not good at programming.

Comment: This is very nice.  To clarify what this solution offers in contrast to the package `appendixnumberbeamer` in @Corentin's answer: `\insertmainframenumber` would normally be used in a beamertheme file.  `appendixnumberbeamer` works without modifying a theme file.  `appendixnumberbeamer` uses a separate total count in the appendix, while `\insertmainframenumber` carries over the total from the main slides.  With the latter, if you have 20 main slides and 5 appendix slides, the last main slide will display 20/20, and the first appendix slide will display 21/20.  Either might be desirable.

Answer (score 7):

Old question and already lots of beamer-only solutions, but an alternate solution could be to build separatly the main presentation and the backup set of slides, and stitch the two pdf files together with `pdftk`. This way they are guaranteed to have separate numbering.

To keep formatting the same, you can put all the header stuff in a separate file, then just `\input` it in the two latex files.

Answer (score 5):

For themes based on the `infolines` outer theme and a beamer version >= 3.49 you can use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]` after your theme to exclude the appendix from framenumbers displayed on the bottom of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First slide}
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```