# Add a number to a parameter

Tags: beamer

I'm doing slides with beamer using the mtheme. This theme includes the slide number in the bottom of the page using this code:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=3ex,dp=3ex,leftskip=0.3cm,rightskip=0.3cm]{structure}%
  \hfill\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertframenumber%
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
```

I wanted to the number to appear as `x/X`, being `X` the total number of slides, which can be displayed via `\inserttotalframenumber`. So i change the third line above to:

```
\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
```

Now, the problem is that I have a slide at the end that should NOT count in the total number of frames, and so the result is that it's showing `x/X`, begin `X` one unit bigger than it should.

How could I do it so it displays `\inserttotaframenumber-1`. I saw `calc` allows for simple calculations but using the package and writing just `\insertotalframenumber-1` does not work.

Can I do this some how?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2541/36296

Answer (score 2):

You can use a counter:

```
\newcounter{mynumber}
\setcounter{mynumber}{\inserttotalframenumber}
\addtocounter{mynumber}{-1}
%% Now use:
\insertframenumber/\themynumber
```

Comment: It's displaying a `0`. And why do you use `\themynumber` instead of `\mynumber`?

Comment: The `0` should be ok, if you have `1` frame. Keep in mind to compile twice!

Comment: @MyUserIsThis: `\the<counter>` is the normal way to access the value of a counter.